# installed package showing not found

Tags: 16.04

I have `libXpm.so.4` in Ubuntu 16.04. It is showing installed in synaptic. But, when I installed IDL then this is the error I got:

```
/home/angel/IDL/idl70/bin/bin.linux.x86/idl: error while loading shared libraries: libXpm.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

On doing `sudo apt-get install libXpm.so.4` I got this:

```
[sudo] password for angel: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libXpm.so.4:i386
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libXpm.so.4'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libXpm.so.4'
```

I checked the synaptic it is installed there.
What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`libXpm.so.4` is the library *file* you get when you install `libxpm`, and is then used by software that requires it.

To get the `libXpm.so.4` library, we should install `libxpm`, version `4`

Therefore, the correct package name is `libxpm4`.

Comment: When I gave this command this is what I get. Its already installed. angel@ideapadS510p:~$ sudo apt-get install libxpm4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libxpm4 is already the newest version (1:3.5.11-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Thanks bharadwaj Raju... I downloaded the same from ubuntu package centre and installed it. Its now working. It didn't work from aptitude and synaptic as it was showing libXpm4 as up-to-date. Downloaded the i386 package of libXpm from the Xenial packages as I'm using Ubuntu 16 Xenial.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the libXpm4 from ubuntu package centre and installed it. Its now working. It didn't work from aptitude and synaptic as it was showing libXpm4 as up-to-date. Downloaded the i386 package of libXpm4 from the Xenial packages as I'm using Ubuntu 16 Xenial. When I clicked on the package, it took me to the software centre, the install option was there and I installed from there. The error of libXpm.so.4 came up when I installed IDL and was calling idl then it showed the error missing library packages libXpm.so.4. On giving the command sudo apt-get install libXpm4 from the terminal, was getting pacakge no found in regex and glob. After downloading and installing from ubuntu package source, IDL is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the fact that the IDL use the i386 architecute instead of the 64. So running

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
apt-get install  libxpm4:i386
```

it work for me.